# Lose focus when hiding system bar

Tags: android, hide, system, lost-focus

I'm using an webview that is displayed on top of the lock screen, also I'm automatically hiding the system bar after a short period of time:

```
/**
 * Class used to hide the device System UI bar.
 * 
 */
public class SystemUiHider {
    /**
     * Delay until to hide the bar.
     */
    private static final int HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

    /**
     * Declare the handler.
     */
    private Handler mHandler;
    /**
     * Declare the view on which to hide the bar.
     */
    private View mView;

    private Utils utils;

    /**
     * Set the class view to be used.
     * 
     * @param view
     */
    public SystemUiHider(final View view, final Context context) {
        this.mView = view;
        this.utils = new Utils(context);

    }

    /**
     * Setup used to hide the system bar and start the handler.
     */
    public final void setup() {
        hideSystemUi();
        this.mHandler = new Handler();
        mView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(final int visibility) {
                if (visibility != View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION) {
                    delay();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Set the flag to hidden for the view.
     */
    private void hideSystemUi() {
        utils.hideSystemBar(WebViewActivity.appContext);
    }

    /**
     * Set the runnable that runs on a different thread to call the method
     * hiding the system bar.
     */
    private Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            hideSystemUi();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Set the delay until to hide the system bar.
     */
    private void delay() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
    }
}
```

And this is the method that hides the system bar:

```
/**
 * Hide system bar.
 * Different methods applied depending on the SDK version
 *
 * @param context
 */
@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void hideSystemBar(Context context) {
    if (SDK_INT < FOURTEEN) {
        Log.i("WebViewClient", "hideSystemBar: < 14 ");
        ((Activity) context).getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN);
    } else if (SDK_INT >= FOURTEEN && SDK_INT < SIXTEEN) {
        Log.i("WebViewClient", "hideSystemBar: 14  - 16");
        ((Activity) context).getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE   // 14
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);                                                         // 14   
    } else if (SDK_INT >= SIXTEEN) {
        Log.i("WebViewClient", "hideSystemBar: > 16");
        ((Activity) context).getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE   // 14
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION                                                           // 14
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);                                                              // 16
    } 
}
```

The problem I'm having is that my webview looses focus when using this. My guess is because of the `((Activity) context).getWindow().getDecorView()`

Is there an alternative way to display the activity on top of the locked screen and hide the system bar without loosing the focus ?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you managed so solve it?

Answer (score 0):

After some search I ended up doing this. Need to test it on other api's but the focus is keept in the app now.

```
private void hideSystemUI() {
    int visibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        visibility |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        visibility |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE;
    }
    getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(visibility);
}
```